# Intercept long media button press and disable Google Now

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, headphones, google-now

I wish to start a reciever\service that recieves the long press from the headset button and disables the Google Now voice recognition feature. Is that possible or is the Google Now response hard-coded to be in higher priority prior to Jelly Bean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have implemented it listening to LongPress of volume key.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
        {
            // do something here
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
```